# Is it possible to sort a list of events?

Tags: c#, sorting, events, event-handling

Suppose I have a class like the below:

```
public class EventClass
{
    public int ExecuteOrder {get; set;}
    public List<EventHandler> Children {get; set;}

    public EventClass(int order)
    {
        ExecuteOrder = order;
        Children = new List<EventHandler>();
    }

    public void OnExecuteA(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something...
    }

    public void OnExecuteB(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something...
    }
}
```

And generate some EventClass like the following:

```
public static void Main()
{
    EventClass parent = new EventClass(0);
    EventClass child1 = new EventClass(1);
    EventClass child2 = new EventClass(2);
    EventClass child3 = new EventClass(3);
    EventClass child4 = new EventClass(4);
    EventClass child5 = new EventClass(5);

    parent.Children.Add(new EventHandler(child3.OnExecuteA()));
    parent.Children.Add(new EventHandler(child1.OnExecuteA()));
    parent.Children.Add(new EventHandler(child4.OnExecuteB()));
    parent.Children.Add(new EventHandler(child5.OnExecuteA()));
    parent.Children.Add(new EventHandler(child2.OnExecuteB()));
    //I didn't add it in order because this part is actually executed throughout 
    //different parts of my project, so I wouldn't know which one is added first, 
    //hence the disordered addition to simulating it.
}
```

So my question is, is it possible to sort the list back to `{child1,child2,child3,child4,child5}` and invoke their events in order?

PS. I can't set the `Children`'s type to `List<EventClass>` because just like you saw above, I want some of the children to execute `OnExecuteA` and some to execute `OnExecuteB`, and I don't how to specify it without any extra information. Such as `List<(int,EventClass)> Children` and do something like

```
foreach((int,EventClass) c in Children)
{
    if(c.Item1 == 0) c.OnExecuteA(null,null);
    else c.OnExecuteB(null,null);
}
```

That's why I think it's better to just set the `Children` as a list of delegates and just add either `OnExecuteA` or `OnExecuteB` to it.

Comment: In theory, you should be able to use a custom comparator and then sort.

Comment: It will be OK if the list was containing the EventClass themselves, but my list was containing "delegates", and I have no idea how to get the residing class itself from a delegate. I don't even know if it's possible.

Comment: Why is `Children` a `List<EventHandler>` rather than a `List<EventClass>`? Currently, the parent knows nothing about the `EventClass` objects where the event handlers belong. If you turn `Children` into a `List<EventClass>`, you can add `child1`, `child2`, etc., then you can directly access the `OnExecute` method of each child.

Comment: Because there are some other concerns I didn't mention (because it's irrelevant to the question). In some way, I find it's better to populate the list with delegates instead of the class themselves unless I can not find the solution for it.

Comment: @Pikachu620 I think it's relevant because this might be an XY problem (i.e., there might be a better solution for what you're actually trying to achieve). Anyway, see my answer below.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine Thank you very much for your answer and suggestion! But since you already have an answer (a great one at that) to this specific question, I think I should leave it as is and ask another question about it.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine As I'm typing the new question, I think I'd better NOT ask it. So I'll just tell you my "other concerns" here instead. If you still think that it's better to post it as a question, then I'll go finish it. What I didn't mention is: Each node actually has 2 methods, let's say `A` and `B`, and I want some of the children to execute `A`, and some to execute `B`. And I don't know how to specify it "from the parent". That's why I was thinking of just populating the list with delegates and just adding either `A` or `B` to it, so it'll know which method to execute.

Comment: @Pikachu620 That sounds like it would be a too-broad/opinion-based question. There are many ways to achieve this but it all depends on the actual requirements. One way would be to have an enum property in the class to indicate which method should be executed. Another is to create an interface and implement it in two or more classes with each having its version of the method. Or if the methods do totally different things, you could inherit an abstract class and selectively add the relevant method in the concrete classes. Etc. etc.

Comment: It is. That's why I'm narrowing it down to "this specific method". I'm not asking "how to achieve it", I would be in big trouble if I did ask something like that. True, there might be many other "better" ways to do it, but currently, this is what I had come up with. And thanks to you, I have a breakthrough. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, it's probably better to have a `List<EventClass>` instead, but if you must do it this way, you can sort the delegates using the `Target` property after casting it to the correct type as follows:

```
parent.Children = parent.Children.OrderBy(d => ((EventClass)d.Target).ExecuteOrder).ToList();
```

You probably could also create an `IComparer` so that you can pass it to `parent.Children.Sort()`, but you might need to create a custom event because it wouldn't be a good idea to just create an `IComparer<EventHandler>` and expect any arbitrary EventHandler delegate's Target to be an `EventClass` instance.